# Unzip and unrar to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, unzip, unrar, sevenzipsharp

My app loads RAR/ZIP archives that contain a large number of images and displays a thumbnail in a Listbox.
I'm using SevenZipSharp at the moment. Afaik it only supports dumping individual files to **disk** - which I'll have to do for each image to get a thumbnail. I think dumping the images to memory will give me at least some improvement in performance. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SevenZipSharp source code, you can see that there are two `SevenZipExtractor.ExtractFile()` overloads that takes a [`System.IO.Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) object as input type:

```
public void ExtractFile(string fileName, Stream stream)
// and
public void ExtractFile(int index, Stream stream) // 'index' is the index in the archive file table.
```

As [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) inherits from `Stream`, you can use one of these functions to achieve what you want.

*Note:* `SevenZipExtractor` has constructors that accept `Stream` object also as input type.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have read the the doc more carefully, thought it only supported FileStreams.